# Odd error in my Java program

Tags: java

I have a Java program that is designed to take an input of customers, then run a loop for each. Then the user has 3 choices to input: clowns, safari sam, or music caravan. I just don't understand what is wrong with my `if` statements. You see, if a user enters "clowns", the corresponding `if` statement works fine and the `if` statement is executed. However, if a user inputs "safari sam" or "music caravan", the `if` statements do not execute.

My question is: If the first `if` statement is executed, then why are the other 2 being skipped (not executing when conditions are met)?

CODE:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;   
    public class FunRentals {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner new_scan = new Scanner(System.in);  
            System.out.println("Enter the amount of customers: ");
            int num_customers = new_scan.nextInt();

            for(int i = 1; i<=num_customers; i++){
                System.out.println("Please enter the service used (\"Clowns\", \"Safari Sam\", or \"Music Caravan\") for customer #"+i);
                String service_type = new_scan.next();
                String service_type_real = service_type.toLowerCase();

                if(service_type_real.equals("clowns")){ 
                    System.out.println("Please enter the amount of ADDITONAL hours");   
                    double additional_hours = new_scan.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("The total bill for customer #" +i +" is "+ clowns(additional_hours));
                } 
                else if(service_type_real.equals("safari sam")){
                    System.out.println("Please enter the amount of ADDITONAL hours");   
                    double additional_hours = new_scan.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("The total bill for customer #" +i +" is "+ safari_sam(additional_hours));
                } 
                else if(service_type_real.equals("music caravan")){
                    System.out.println("Please enter the amount of ADDITONAL hours");   
                    double additional_hours = new_scan.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("The total bill for customer #" +i +" is "+ music_caravan(additional_hours));
                }

            }

        }

        public static double clowns(double a){
            double additional_cost = a*35;
            double total_cost = additional_cost + 45;
            return total_cost;
        }

        public static double safari_sam(double a){
            double additional_cost = a*45;
            double total_cost = additional_cost + 55;
            return total_cost;
        }
        public static double music_caravan(double a){
            double additional_cost = a*30;
            double total_cost = additional_cost + 40;
            return total_cost;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try printing the value of service_type_real right after you assign it; you should see the problem then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `nextLine()` instead of `next()` to read user input. `nextLine()` will read the entire line, but `next()` will only read the next word.

Answer (score 1):

For reading String provided by the user in console you have to use .nextLine()
So try by using this -

```
 String service_type = new_scan.nextLine();
```

This should store the value of whatever you are providing in the console to the String "service_type".